# Using onClick in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, onclick

I want to add a comment each time I click the button, here is my `addComment` fucntion

```
addComment: function(text){
            console.log('adding');
            var arr = this.state.comments;
            arr.push(text);
            this.setState({comments:arr});
            },
```

and my `render`

```
render: function(){
        return(
        <div>
            <button onCLick={this.addComment.bind(null,'new')} className="button-info create">Add new</button>
            <div className="board">{
            this.state.comments.map(this.eachComment)}
            </div>
        </div>
        );
        }
```

the whole code is here: https://ghostbin.com/paste/895eb

the problem is there is no error showing in my console and when I click the button, nothing happens.

Can anyone help me find the bug please?

Comment: typo, use `onClick`, instead of `onCLick` and use `bind(this, 'new')`, write it like this: `<button onClick={this.addComment.bind(this,'new')} className="button-info create">Add new</button>`

Comment: I have been looking at it for 40 minutes and not see the typo. Thank you Mayank.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you. I think problem i you used onCLick instead of onclick
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to bind (this) or what ever to function , instead try to use arrow function ([ECMA SCRIPT arrow function](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/09/10/understanding-ecmascript-6-arrow-functions/)) which will handle (_this, _self, _that , ...)

```js
addComment(text){
            console.log('adding');
            var arr = this.state.comments;
            arr.push(text);
            this.setState({comments:arr});
}
```

```html
        <div>
            <button onCLick={() => addComment('new')} className="button-info create">Add new</button>
            <div className="board">{
            this.state.comments.map(this.eachComment)}
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be onClick instead of onCLick.

```
<button onClick={this.addComment.bind(null,'new')} className="button-info create">Add new</button>
```

Here is the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/jayesh24/td1v0kh4/